# No se procesan correctamente los nuevos valores de 3 select dependientes

Tags: formularios, symfony3, forms-events

En el formulario IngresoType tengo 3 select dependientes: salaDeIngreso, cubiculoDeIngreso y camaDeIngreso. La entidad Ingreso relacionada al formulario tambien tiene una relación con la entidad UnidadDeIngreso, y a partir de ahí es donde comienza la dependencia: Cuando se va a registrar un ingreso en una unidad de ingreso el select salaDeIngreso solo carga las salas de esa unidad que estén disponibles, y así sucecivamente con las entidades cubiculo y cama. El problema lo tengo en el evento PRE_SUBMIT del formulario, que al ocurrir un error de validación en el formulario, carga todos los registros existentes en los 3 select y no los registros asociados a la unidad de ingreso, así como los disponibles.
Esta es mi clase del formulario ingreso:

```
class IngresoType extends AbstractType {

    private $em;
    private $uuidEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, UuidEncoder $uuidEncoder) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->uuidEncoder = $uuidEncoder;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {


        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            if ($data->getId() === null) {
                $form->add('embarazada', EntityIdType::class, array(
                    'data_class' => Embarazada::class,
                    'empty_data' => null
                ));

                $form->add('fechaIngreso', DateType::class, array(
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'input' => 'datetime',
                    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                    'html5' => false,
                    'compound' => false,
                    'label' => 'Fecha de Ingreso',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'js-datepicker')
                ));

                $form->add('nombre_embarazada', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Nombre Embarazada',
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'attr' => array('readonly' => true)
                ));
                $form->add('numeroIdentidad', TextType::class, array(
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'label' => 'Número de Identidad',
                    'attr' => array('maxlength' => '11'),
                ));

                $form->add('motivoDelIngreso', TextareaType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Motivo del Ingreso',
                ));

                $unidadIngreso = $data->getUnidadDeIngreso();
                $salas = $this->em->getRepository(EstructuraOrganizativa::class)->obtenerSalasDisponiblesParaIngreso($unidadIngreso);
//                foreach ($salas as $s) {
//                    $s->setIdPublico($this->uuidEncoder->encode($s->getIdPublico()));
//                }
                $form->add('salaDeIngreso', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Sala:',
                    'class' => SalaDeIngresos::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'nombre',
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'empty_data' => null,
                    'choices' => $salas,
                ));
            }
            else {
                $form->add('id', HiddenType::class, array(
                    'data_class' => Ingreso::class,
                    'mapped' => false
                ));
                $form->add('fechaEgreso', DateType::class, array(
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'input' => 'datetime',
                    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                    'html5' => false,
                    'compound' => false,
                    'label' => 'Fecha de Ingreso',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'js-datepicker'),
                ));

                $form->add('nombre_embarazada', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Nombre Embarazada',
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => $data->getEmbarazada()->getNombre(),
                    'empty_data' => $data->getEmbarazada()->getNombre(),
                    'attr' => array('readonly' => true)
                ));

                $form->add('anotacionAlEgresar', TextareaType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Nota del Egreso',
                ));

                $form->add('ingresoFinalizadoPorFuga', CheckboxType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Abandono'
                ));

                $form->add('ingresoFinalizadoPorParto', CheckboxType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Parto'
                ));

                $form->add('ingresoFinalizadoPorMuerteMaterna', CheckboxType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Muerte Materna'
                ));

                $form->add('ingresoFinalizadoPorPerdidaEmbarazo', CheckboxType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Pérdida del Embarazo'
                ));

                $form->add('criterioUbicacionNuevo', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Criterio de Ubicación',
                    'class' => CriterioUbicacion::class,
                    'empty_data' => $data->getEmbarazada()->getUbicacion(),
                    'mapped' => false
                ));
            }
        });

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();
            if (is_null($data->getId())) {
                $cubiculos = $this->em->getRepository(Cubiculo::class)->obtenerDisponiblesParaIngreso($data->getSalaDeIngreso());
//                foreach ($cubiculos as $c) {
//                    $c->setIdPublico($this->uuidEncoder->encode($c->getIdPublico()));
//                }
                $form->add('cubiculoDeIngreso', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Cubículo:',
                    'class' => Cubiculo::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'nombre',
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'empty_data' => null,
                    'choices' => $cubiculos,
                ));
            }
        });

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            if (is_null($data->getId())) {
                $camas = $this->em->getRepository(Cama::class)->obtenerDisponiblesParaIngreso($data->getCubiculoDeIngreso());
//                foreach ($camas as $c) {
//                    $c->setIdPublico($this->uuidEncoder->encode($c->getIdPublico()));
//                }
                $form->add('camaDeIngreso', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Cama:',
                    'class' => Cama::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'numero',
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'empty_data' => null,
                    'choices' => $camas,
                    'placeholder' => '-- Seleccione --'
                ));
            }
        });

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            if (false === array_key_exists('id', $data)) {

                $sala = $this->em->getRepository(SalaDeIngresos::class)->find($data['salaDeIngreso']);
//                $sala = $this->em->getRepository(SalaDeIngresos::class)->findOneBy(array('idPublico' => $this->uuidEncoder->decode($data['salaDeIngreso'])));
                $form->add('salaDeIngreso', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Sala:',
                    'class' => SalaDeIngresos::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'nombre',
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'empty_data' => null,
                    'data' => $sala,
                ));

                $cubiculo = $this->em->getRepository(Cubiculo::class)->find($data['cubiculoDeIngreso']);
//                $cubiculo = $this->em->getRepository(Cubiculo::class)->findOneBy(array('idPublico' => $this->uuidEncoder->decode($data['cubiculoDeIngreso'])));
                $form->add('cubiculoDeIngreso', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Cubículo:',
                    'class' => Cubiculo::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'nombre',
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'empty_data' => null,
                    'data' => $cubiculo,
                ));

                $cama = $this->em->getRepository(Cama::class)->find($data['camaDeIngreso']);
//                $cama = $this->em->getRepository(Cama::class)->findOneBy(array('idPublico' => $this->uuidEncoder->decode($data['camaDeIngreso'])));
                $form->add('camaDeIngreso', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Cama:',
                    'class' => Cama::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'numero',
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'empty_data' => null,
                    'data' => $cama,
                    'placeholder' => '-- Seleccione --'
                ));
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Ingreso::class,
            'attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off'),
        ));
    }
```

El código anterior se puede refactorizar al máximo, pero lo que deseo es entender el trabajo con los enventos PRE_SET_DATA y PRE_SUBMIT.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer un poco más sencilla la solución, separé en dos formularios la apertura y el cierre de un ingreso. Los tres select dependientes solamente aparecen en el formulario de apertura de ingreso, denominado `IngresoType`.

```
class IngresoType extends AbstractType {

    private $em;
    private $uuidEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, UuidEncoder $uuidEncoder) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->uuidEncoder = $uuidEncoder;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('unidadDeIngreso', EstructuraOrganizativaIdPublicoType::class);

        $builder->add('embarazada', EntityIdPublicoType::class, array(
            'data_class' => Embarazada::class,
            'empty_data' => null
        ));

        $builder->add('fechaIngreso', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'input' => 'datetime',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'html5' => false,
            'compound' => false,
            'label' => 'Fecha de Ingreso',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'js-datepicker')
        ));

        $builder->add('nombre_embarazada', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Nombre Embarazada',
            'mapped' => false,
            'attr' => array('readonly' => true)
        ));

        $builder->add('numeroIdentidad', TextType::class, array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => 'Número de Identidad',
            'attr' => array('maxlength' => '11'),
        ));

        $builder->add('motivoDelIngreso', TextareaType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Motivo del Ingreso',
        ));

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetDataCubiculo'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmitCubiculo'));
    }

    protected function addElements(FormInterface $form, SalaDeIngresos $salaDeIngresos = null, EstructuraOrganizativa $unidadDeIngresos = null) {
        $salas = (null === $unidadDeIngresos) ? array() : $this->em->getRepository(EstructuraOrganizativa::class)->obtenerSalasDisponiblesParaIngreso($unidadDeIngresos);
        $form->add('salaDeIngreso', EntityType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Sala de Ingreso:',
            'class' => SalaDeIngresos::class,
            'choice_label' => 'nombre',
            'choice_value' => 'id',
            'empty_data' => null,
            'choices' => $salas,
            'placeholder' => '-- Seleccione --'
        ));


        $cubiculos = (null === $salaDeIngresos) ? array() : $this->em->getRepository(Cubiculo::class)->obtenerDisponiblesParaIngreso($salaDeIngresos);
        $form->add('cubiculoDeIngreso', EntityType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Cubículo:',
            'class' => Cubiculo::class,
            'choice_label' => 'nombre',
            'choice_value' => 'id',
            'empty_data' => null,
            'choices' => $cubiculos,
            'placeholder' => '-- Seleccione --'
        ));
    }

    function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        $unidadDeIngresos = $this->em->getRepository(EstructuraOrganizativa::class)->findOneJoinTipoEstructuraOrganizativa($this->uuidEncoder->decode($data['unidadDeIngreso']));
        $salaDeIngresos = $this->em->getRepository(SalaDeIngresos::class)->find($data['salaDeIngreso']);
        $this->addElements($form, $salaDeIngresos, $unidadDeIngresos);
    }

    function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event) {
        $ingreso = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $unidadDeIngresos = $ingreso->getUnidadDeIngreso();
        $this->addElements($form, $ingreso->getSalaDeIngreso(), $unidadDeIngresos);
    }

    protected function addElementsCamas(FormInterface $form, Cubiculo $cubiculoDeIngresos = null) {
        $camas = (null === $cubiculoDeIngresos) ? array() : $this->em->getRepository(Cama::class)->obtenerDisponiblesParaIngreso($cubiculoDeIngresos);
        $form->add('camaDeIngreso', EntityType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Camas disponible:',
            'class' => Cama::class,
            'choice_label' => 'numero',
            'choice_value' => 'id',
            'empty_data' => null,
            'choices' => $camas,
            'placeholder' => '-- Seleccione --'
        ));
    }

    function onPreSubmitCubiculo(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        $cubiculoDeIngresos = $this->em->getRepository(Cubiculo::class)->find($data['cubiculoDeIngreso']);
        $this->addElementsCamas($form, $cubiculoDeIngresos);
    }

    function onPreSetDataCubiculo(FormEvent $event) {
        $ingreso = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $this->addElementsCamas($form, $ingreso->getCubiculoDeIngreso());
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Ingreso::class,
            'attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off'),
        ));
    }
```

En la definición del formulario empleé dos eventos `PRE_SET_DATA` y 2 eventos `PRE_SUBMIT`, que se encargarán de "popular" el widget "salaDeIngreso" y a la vez "crear en cadena" los widget dependientes `cubiculoDeingreso` y `camaDeIngreso`.
Por úlitmo en la vista del formulario el código javascript que manejará los eventos `change`de los widgets `salaDeIngreso` y `cubiculoDeIngreso`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#ingreso_salaDeIngreso').on('change', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var selectSala = $(this);
            var selectCubiculos = $('#ingreso_cubiculoDeIngreso');
            var selectCamas = $('#ingreso_camaDeIngreso');
            var idSel = selectSala.val();
            if (idSel != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    'datatype': 'JSON',
                    'url': Routing.generate('app_salaIngreso_cubiculos', {'sala': idSel}),
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#indicador').addClass('cargando-satisfactorio').slideDown('fast');
                    }
                }).done(function (salas) {
                    selectCubiculos.html('').append('<option value="" selected="selected">-- Seleccione --</option>');
                    selectCamas.html('').append('<option value="" selected="selected">-- Seleccione --</option>');
                    $.each(salas, function (key, m) {
                        selectCubiculos.append('<option value="' + m.id + '">' + m.nombre + '</option>')
                    });
                }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                        window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                    } else {
                        $('#indicador').removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').addClass('cargando-error').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                }).always(function () {
                    if (!$('#indicador').hasClass('cargando-satisfactorio')) {

                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#indicador').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                                $(this).removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                            });
                        }, 0);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                selectCubiculos.html('').append('<option value="" selected="selected">-- Seleccione --</option>');
                selectCamas.html('').append('<option value="" selected="selected">-- Seleccione --</option>');
            }
        });


        $('#ingreso_cubiculoDeIngreso').on('change', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var selectCubiculo = $(this);
            var selectCamas = $('#ingreso_camaDeIngreso');
            var idSel = selectCubiculo.val();
            if (idSel != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    'datatype': 'JSON',
                    'url': Routing.generate('app_salaIngreso_camas', {'cubiculo': idSel}),
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#indicador').addClass('cargando-satisfactorio').slideDown('fast');
                    }
                }).done(function (camas) {
                    selectCamas.html('').append('<option value="" selected="selected">-- Seleccione --</option>');

                    $.each(camas, function (key, m) {
                        selectCamas.append('<option value="' + m.id + '">' + m.numero + '</option>');
                    });
                }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                        window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                    } else {
                        $('#indicador').removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').addClass('cargando-error').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                }).always(function () {
                    if (!$('#indicador').hasClass('cargando-satisfactorio')) {

                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#indicador').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                                $(this).removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                            });
                        }, 0);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                selectCamas.html('').append('<option value="" selected="selected">-- Seleccione --</option>');
            }
        });
});
```